# Simple regular expression using preg_match

Tags: preg-match

I am trying to retrieve the three digit number after this word and semi colon.

REF: 222

The code i have below works but its not good because its getting 3digit numbers from the $decoded_message string.

What i really want is only to grab three digit number after the word REF: ###

```
if (preg_match("([0-9]{3})", $decoded_message, $matches)) {
  echo "Match was found <br />";
  echo "ref = ".$matches[0];

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for `REF: [0-9]{3}` and then remove the `REF:` part.

```
if (preg_match("/REF: [0-9]{3}/", $decoded_message, $matches)) {
  echo "Match was found <br />";
  echo "ref = ".substr( $matches[0], 5 );
}
```

Comment: does preg match search the html or the output of the html? i cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: is the ,5 in the substr for the amount of characters to count to get to the first digit? of the ref no.?

Comment: It skips 5 characters from the start (`REF:` + space). `$matches[0]` will contain `REF: ###` if there is a match.

Comment: this is driving me nuts... still wont work and i have tried everything .. i even copied the blank spaces between the REF: and the 3 digits and used character counts online to get the exact number of spaces but no luck. What if there was a Hash symbol in front of the three digits ? #871 - what would my preg_match look like then?

Comment: Well, it would look the same except with a hash in front: `/REF: #[0-9]{3}/`. Seems to me that your input is not what you think it is, or reading between the lines, there might be HTML tags inside it. If you do `$decoded_message = "foo REF: 123 bar"` I'm quite sure it would find the 123 in there.

Comment: thanks. its working. I have told the team to add a simple # to the front of the 3 digit reference number. Now we can collect and store. phew!! thankyou! i now simply have no spaces so the maths is as simple as #REF:### with no spaces anywhere it works a treat :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may simply replace "REF: " by using

```
$output = preg_replace("/REF: /","", "REF: 222");
```

Afterwards, only the number should be contained in $output.

Comment: how does it know to scan my $decoded_message string? 

because im getting no result from it.

Comment: Well, the last parameter of preg_replace is the string in which content is to be replaced. So if you are wanting to replace "REF: " from `$decoded_message` you need to process  `$output = preg_replace("/REF: /","",  $decoded_message);`. Does this work for you?

Comment: Hi Johannes, my bad. I should have explained that decoded message contains a page of html with tables etc... within that html structure is the REF: ###

Comment: $output = preg_replace("/REF: /","", $decoded_message);
echo $output;

not giving me anything yet :)

Comment: Oh, seems like I was quite wrong about you wanted. Seemed too easy anyways;) Then try this, like Juhana proposed: `if (preg_match("/REF: [0-9]{3}/", $decoded_message, $matches)) {
  echo "Match was found <br />";
  echo "ref = ".preg_replace("/REF: /","",$matches[0]);
}`

Comment: this is driving me nuts... still wont work and i have tried everything .. i even copied the blank spaces between the REF: and the 3 digits and used character counts online to get the exact number of spaces but no luck. What if there was a Hash symbol in front of the three digits ? #871 - what would my preg_match look like then?

Comment: We could try something like `preg_match("/REF:[^a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]{3}/)` for looking for REF:<something neither a letter nor a digit>222. Otherwise you could provide more information such as some of the content of your $decoded_message and your php code by editing your question.